# Puppeteer and dynamically added iFrame (element)

Tags: javascript, protractor, puppeteer

We have an angularJs application that popup a modal form (component) on button pressed.
This component loads an iFrame, which I cannot seem to access with Puppeteer.
Have tried with **mainFrame**.

```
    await page.waitFor(15000);
    const frame = page.mainFrame().childFrames().find((iframe) => {
      console.log('FRAME', iframe.name(), iframe.url());
      return iframe.name() === 'iFrameName';
    });
```

The above only has one frame (the main frame/window).

Have tried with **frames**

```
    await page.waitFor(15000);
    const frame = page.frames().find((iframe) => {
      console.log('FRAME', iframe.name(), iframe.url());
      return iframe.name() === 'iFrameName';
    });
```

Have tried with **contentFrame**

```
    await page.waitForSelector('iframe', { visible: true, timeout: 2000 });
    const elementHandle = await page.$('iframe');
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
```

With the above, *elementHandle* has a value but *frame* is null

We have this working with **Protractor**, were hopping to move to Puppeteers but if there is no solution will have to stick with Protractor (which has it own other issues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no support for [`out-of-process iframes (OOPIFs)`](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/oop-iframes/oop-iframes-rendering). To be able to work with them, you need to launch Chromium with `--disable-features=site-per-process`:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--disable-features=site-per-process']
    });
```

You can track puppeteer's issue/support [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2548).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, an iframe dynamically called, so that src=(unknown) with a JS

`href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(VARİABLES,,true,,false,))`

is it possible to clone The or an iframe via invoking js calling it in puppeteer? if so you can try.